# Can REST endpoints be used generically to support reuse by different resources?

Tags: web-services, rest, http

Is it appropriate to design a RESTful service that has a single, generic endpoint that can be reused for arbitrary business operations? For example, one web app might need data relating to vendors. It could call the REST api, passing the name of the class method that that api should call internally to get vendor data. Another app could use the same generic api endpoint and pass the name of another business entity to get different data back.

My motivation is that we have a large set of business-related objects and data. Making api endpoints for each individual one seems like overkill. Can't the REST api be used instead as a kind of dumb pass-through?

Answer (score 1):

It can, but in that case it has nothing to do with "REST" anymore. You'll be simply doing RPC-over-HTTP.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that is what I am interested in. It feels wrong to me to build out a huge REST api to handle all the different business transactions we might need when, essentially, each of those api endpoints will just be shuttling things to another layer in the stack anyway. What is the advantage of building out a REST endpoint for each resource type in this situation?